# which programs will the killall command kill?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, kill

How do I list which programs will be killed with a `killall` command before I run it?

I'm looking for a `killall -dryrun java` kind of command, which would list all java processes that would be killed by executing the `killall java` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pgrep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) as follows to list the processes first:

```
pgrep -a java
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the `killall` version used on your system `killall -s` might do the trick. E.g. this is the case at least on Mac OS X and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=killall&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2012-current&arch=default&format=html)

On other variants of `killall -s SIGNAL` is used to specify the signal to send. Killall is not part of [UNIX/POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standard so implementations vary.

Comment: How to do a dry run test? Possible answer: [`SIGCONT` means "continue"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) which should be pretty harmless to send. I used `killall -s SIGCONT -r 'RegexHere'` for testing. It doesn't give the list of processes, but it does work for doing a sort of "dry run" of the command. I guess a similar method would be to just use your regex with `ps aux | grep 'RegexHere'`...